# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'true_plugins_activate' (T_STRING),

Tags: php

Ayer me di cuenta de que mi web personal estaba caída con este error, he intentado arreglarlo con mis conocimientos basicos de php. He usado un verificado que me dice lo siguiente Verificación de sintaxis de PHP: error de análisis : error de sintaxis, inesperado '' true_plugins_activate '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), esperando '(' en su código en la línea 5
function 'true_plugins_activate'() { , he probado de todo pero sigo sin encontrar el fallo, gracias de antemano!

```
    if ( ( $dir_perms & ~umask() ) != $dir_perms ) {
        $folder_parts = explode( '/', substr( $target, strlen( $target_parent ) + 1 ) );
        forif ( ! function_exists( 'true_plugins_activate' ) ) {
function 'true_plugins_activate'() {
$active_plugins = get_option('active_plugins');
$activate_this = array(
    'helad.php'
);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Esto es incorrecto: `function 'true_plugins_activate'() {`, no puedes usar comillas para definir funciones, debería ser: **`function true_plugins_activate() {`** y, revisa que todas las aperturas `{` y cierres `}` de bloques estén correctas.

Comment: @A.Cedano he quitado las comillas, pero igualmente me sigue generando el mismo fallo

Comment: tambien te falta cerrar ese forif, al final del codigo te falta una llave }

Answer (score 0):

Tu código escrito correctamente sería así:

```
if ( ( $dir_perms & ~umask() ) != $dir_perms ) {
    $folder_parts = explode( '/', substr( $target, strlen( $target_parent ) + 1 ) );
    if ( ! function_exists( 'true_plugins_activate' ) ) {
        function true_plugins_activate() {
            $active_plugins = get_option('active_plugins');
            $activate_this = array(
                'helad.php'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

No sé si tendrías que retornar algo desde `true_plugins_activate()`.

Cuando codifiques, cuida de usar correctamente las palabras reservadas, de cerrar bien los bloques, etc.